# Merging data in a list based on date

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a generic list which is using this class

```
public class Data
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int OkRecords { get; set; }
    public int ErrorRecords { get; set; }
}
```

I also have `List<string>` which holds unique Dates. I need to add data of original list in such a way that there should be only one record for a date i.e. if there are 10 unique dates then there should be only 10 records filtered out of the original list. I have implemented the following logic but it is taking way too much time if there is more than 100 000 data.

```
int distinctDatesCount = distinctDates.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < distinctDatesCount; i++)
{
    string date = distinctDates[i];
    int ok = 0, error = 0;
    foreach (var item in dataList.Where(w => w.Date == date))
    {
        ok += item.OkRecords;
        error += item.ErrorRecords;
    }
    Data dataValues = new Data
    {
        Date = date,
        OkRecords = ok,
        ErrorRecords = error
    };
    DataListCombined.Add(dataValues);
}
```

DataListCombined is the list in which I am storing the newly merged data.

I've stored the date in string format as I am using it elsewhere where it is required in string format.

Comment: You can use lInq GroupBy to group by data and then aggregate the counts into single objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) to group by data by date and then use [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) to add up the counts into single objects.

```
var DataListCombined = dataList.GroupBy(data => data.Date)
                           .Select(groupedData => 
                               new Data {
                                   Date = groupedData.Key,
                                   OkRecords = groupedData.Sum(item => item.OkRecords),
                                   ErrorRecords = groupedData.Sum(item => item.ErrorRecords)
                               })
                            .Where(data => distinctDates.Contains(data.Date))
                            .ToList();
```

You can also check this resource for more examples.

[101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: @IvanStoev added

Answer (score 1):

Personnally i used a group join. Because record in the DataList shouldn't be in the final result.

```
public class Data
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int OkRecords { get; set; }
    public int ErrorRecords { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<string> distinctDates = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            distinctDates.Add( rand.Next(1, 12) + "/" + rand.Next(1, 30) + "/1");
        }

        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            dataList.Add(new Data{ Date = rand.Next(1,12)+"/"+rand.Next(1, 30)+"/1", OkRecords=0, ErrorRecords=1});
        }

        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Method1(distinctDates, dataList);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);

        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();
        Method2(distinctDates, dataList);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Method1(List<string> distinctDates, List<Data> dataList)
    {
        List<Data> DataListCombined = new List<Data>();
        int distinctDatesCount = distinctDates.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < distinctDatesCount; i++)
        {
            string date = distinctDates[i];
            int ok = 0, error = 0;

            foreach (var item in dataList.Where(w => w.Date == date))
            {
                ok += item.OkRecords;
                error += item.ErrorRecords;
            }
            Data dataValues = new Data
            {
                Date = date,
                OkRecords = ok,
                ErrorRecords = error
            };
            DataListCombined.Add(dataValues);
        }
    }

    private static void Method2(List<string> distinctDates, List<Data> dataList)
    {
        List<Data> DataListCombined = distinctDates.GroupJoin(
            dataList,
            distinctDateItem => distinctDateItem,
            dataListItem => dataListItem.Date,
            (dataListItem, distinctDateItems) => new Data
            {
                ErrorRecords = distinctDateItems.Sum(item => item.ErrorRecords),
                OkRecords = distinctDateItems.Sum(item => item.OkRecords),
                Date = dataListItem
            }
            ).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach as well. I did not quite understand what you meant by `Because record in the DataList shouldn't be in the final result`. Can you clarify that?

Comment: When you merge it like merge in database. You have three case:
1. Date is present in both side
2. Date is only in distinctDates
3. Date is only in dataList
For each you will have in return one Data instance. But how do you want to merge. You can say :
- If date is present only distinctDates thent my result should have an instance of this date (What you and I have done)
- If date is present only in DataList then thent my result should have an instance of this date
- The date must be in both to have a corresponding date